# Unexpected variable results printed in console

Tags: ios, swift, string, realm

For a number of Realm entities, I want to print information on each to the console, using this UIAlertController:

```
@IBAction func addAccountButton(_ sender: Any) {

    // Pop alert to add new account

    let addAcctAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Create New Account", message: "Please name your new account", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    addAcctAlert.addTextField{ (accountTextField) in
        accountTextField.placeholder = "Enter new account name"
        accountTextField.keyboardType = .`default`
    }

    addAcctAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { action in

        // Create new Account with name, balance, isCurrent, save to disk

        let newAccount = Account()
        newAccount.name = self.accountTextField.text!
        newAccount.isCurrent = false
        newAccount.highWaterBalance = 0.0

        // Adds the newly created account

        Account.add(thisAccount: newAccount)

        let realm = try! Realm()
        let currentAccounts = realm.objects(Account.self)

        print ("In AddAccountButton func:")
        print("There are \(String(describing: currentAccounts.count)) Account objects")

        for acct in currentAccounts{
            print("acct.name is \(acct.name)")
            print("acct.highWaterBalance is \(String(describing: acct.highWaterBalance))")
            print("acct.isCurrent is \(String(describing: acct.isCurrent))")

        }
    }))

    addAcctAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(addAcctAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Here's what I get, although each property is assigned a value when the new object is created:

```
There are 4 Account objects
acct.name is 
acct.highWaterBalance is nil
acct.isCurrent is false
acct.name is 
acct.highWaterBalance is nil
acct.isCurrent is false
acct.name is 
acct.highWaterBalance is nil
acct.isCurrent is false
acct.name is 
acct.highWaterBalance is nil
acct.isCurrent is false
```

The only property printing as expected is `acct.isCurrent`. I don't understand why I'm not seeing `.name` (declared as `dynamic var name = ""`) or why `.highWaterBalance` (declared as `dynamic var highWaterBalance: Float?`) is printing as `nil`. As seen in the code above, specific values are assigned to each property.

I'm new to Swift, but have researched quite a bit before asking. I would sure appreciate any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong.

TIA!

**-----------------**

**Edit 1:**

Here are the relevant portions of the Model, per requests below:

import Foundation
import RealmSwift

@objcMembers class Account: Object {

```
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var currentBalance: Float?
dynamic var highWaterBalance: Float?
dynamic var isCurrent: Bool = false
```

}

extension Account {

```
// Adds an item in realm, a new transaction object

@discardableResult
static func add(thisAccount: Account, in realm: Realm = try! Realm())
    -> Account {
        let account = Account()
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(account)
        }
        return account
}
```

**-----------------**

**Edit 2:**

OK, in an attempt to incorporate the suggestions and answers below by simplifying
my code, I removed the extension function from my `Account` class definition. Now I'm using the two following functions, `testForActiveAccount` and `addAccountButton`. The first checks to see if there are already `Account` objects saved, and the second is intended to create and persist a new `Account` object.

Now, `testForActiveAccount`seems to work properly--if there are no accounts, it creates and names one and persists it to disk. It then prints out the proof in the form of a named account with properly attributed properties.

However, `addAccountButton`--which uses essentially identical code--appears to create an empty `Account` object, with nil or empty properties.

I'm guessing, that in my inexperience with both Swift and with Realm, that I'm making a wrong assumption or missing a key concept.

Here are the entire functions for comparison:

```
func testForActiveAccount(){

    let realm = try! Realm()
    let accounts = realm.objects(Account.self)
    let primaryAccount = Account()

    if accounts.count < 1 {
        primaryAccount.name = "Primary Account"
        primaryAccount.isCurrent = true
        primaryAccount.highWaterBalance = 0.00

        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(primaryAccount)
        }
        self.activeAcctLabel.text = primaryAccount.name
        self.currentAccount = primaryAccount

        for acct in accounts{

            print ("In testForActiveAccount func:\n")
            print("There are \(String(describing: accounts.count)) Account objects \n")

            print("acct.name is \(acct.name)")
            print("acct.highWaterBalance is \(String(describing: acct.highWaterBalance))")
            print("acct.isCurrent is \(String(describing: acct.isCurrent))")

        }
    }
}


@IBAction func addAccountButton(_ sender: Any) {

    // Pop alert to add new account

    let addAcctAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Create New Account", message: "Please name your new account", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    addAcctAlert.addTextField{ (accountTextField) in
        accountTextField.placeholder = "Enter new account name"
        accountTextField.keyboardType = .`default`
    }

    addAcctAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: UIAlertActionStyle.destructive, handler: { action in

        // Create new Account with name, balance, isCurrent, save to disk

        let realm = try! Realm()
        let newAccount = Account()
        newAccount.name = self.accountTextField.text!
        newAccount.isCurrent = false
        newAccount.highWaterBalance = 0.0

        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(newAccount)
        }

        let currentAccounts = realm.objects(Account.self)

        print ("In AddAccountButton func:")
        print("There are \(String(describing: currentAccounts.count)) Account objects \n")

        for acct in currentAccounts{
            print("acct.name is \(acct.name)")
            print("acct.highWaterBalance is \(String(describing: acct.highWaterBalance))")
                print("acct.isCurrent is \(String(describing: acct.isCurrent))\n")

        }

    }))

    addAcctAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(addAcctAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

And here are the printouts for each function:

```
In testForActiveAccount func:

There are 1 Account objects 

acct.name is Primary Account
acct.highWaterBalance is nil
acct.isCurrent is true

In AddAccountButton func:
There are 2 Account objects 

acct.name is Primary Account
acct.highWaterBalance is nil
acct.isCurrent is true

acct.name is 
acct.highWaterBalance is nil
acct.isCurrent is false
```

I know I must be doing something simple and stupid--I just don't know what. Any ideas?

Comment: Would you share your realm model too ?

Comment: What's inside Account.add(thisAccount

Comment: Please see edit above!

Comment: Please see new edit above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much investigation guided by the answers above, I still have the problem described here. However, I believe I've isolated the culprit to something not associated with the improper saving methods suspected in this thread--`String literals` vs `UITextField.text` as a source for a Realm property defines as a `String`...

Accordingly, since the problem persists, I've restated the issue in this [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833084/assign-text-from-uitextfield-to-string-property-on-realm-object).

Many thanks for your help here! I still need guidance, so if interested, please check out the new question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem you insert empty instance other than the parameter

```
let account = Account()
try! realm.write {
     realm.add(account)
}
```

It should be

```
realm.add(thisAccount)
```

Also no need for the return as you already have the instance when you call this method , also i see you ignore it in call

Comment: Am trying suggestions, but am not sure I understand. Can you please specify the correct form and location of both the add function and the call from the UIAlertController?

Comment: @rattletrap99 why do you first give in `add(thisAccount:in:)` the `thisAccount` Variable and then do not add it to Realm as expected but instead create an empty Account object with `Account()` and then insert that empty one into Realm? Inserting empty Account objects obviously leads to empty variable entries which you print quite nicely ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should try it with a non-static extension method, it seems clearer and easier to use:

```
func add(in realm: Realm = try! Realm()) {
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(self)
    }
}
```